# vue ssr how to add attributes in script tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use the doc guid with https://ssr.vuejs.org/, but I can not find any way to add custom attributes on the script tag 。 I want to add `crossorigin="anonymous` on the script tag to get the correct error  not  'Script  Error'  。

Comment: Let's provide some code how do you do right now so everyone can redirect you the right way

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to add custom attr for scaript tag，
just use ·Manual Asset Injection· then the script string you will get，and then change it。
the doc is here ：https://ssr.vuejs.org/zh/guide/build-config.html#%E5%AE%A2%E6%88%B7%E7%AB%AF%E9%85%8D%E7%BD%AE-client-config

the code blow ：

```js
    const content = await bundleRenderer.renderToString(context);
    console.log('context.renderResourceHints()',context.renderResourceHints())
    console.log('context.renderStyles()',context.renderStyles())
    console.log('context.renderScripts()',context.renderScripts())

    const html = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ${context.renderResourceHints()}
    ${context.renderStyles()}
    <title>Hello Vue 13</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">${content}</div>
    ${context.renderScripts()}
  </body>
</html>  
    `.trim();

    res.send(html);
```

the result is:

```js
context.renderResourceHints() <link rel="preload" href="/dist/manifest.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/dist/css/styles.css" as="style"><link rel="preload" href="/dist/js/styles.5d70cd50ea7f1b9c411b.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/dist/js/vendors~app.4be2234d42fb0ae60615.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/dist/js/app.5db4c221de97601de33e.js" as="script"><link rel="prefetch" href="/dist/js/about.8e31d4893b2bd4ba6eee.js"><link rel="prefetch" href="/dist/js/blank.d47479964602e2a1ba7b.js">
context.renderStyles() <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/styles.css">
context.renderScripts() <script src="/dist/manifest.js" defer></script><script src="/dist/js/styles.5d70cd50ea7f1b9c411b.js" defer></script><script src="/dist/js/vendors~app.4be2234d42fb0ae60615.js" defer></script><script src="/dist/js/app.5db4c221de97601de33e.js" defer></script>
```

we get the string we can change it right？